# How to get the area of a bounding box using PostGIS 2.2?

Tags: postgis, extents, geonames

As someone who is doing a data integrity check of Geonames, I've found that about 10 percent of the data contain multiple sets of coordinates (longitude, latitude) for a place name within a country. For example, Krajan in ID has 1,151 unique coordinate pairs attributed to it.

I want to know how dispersed the coordinate pairs are for places with more than one pairing. This is an analysis of all places within Geonames modified as recently as 2016-03-04. My analysis is available on GitHub, and you can [fork it here](https://github.com/tbonza/geonames).

To figure out the dispersion of place names with more than one set of coordinates, I first converted the coordinates provided by Geonames to the geography datatype. I then ran the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    "country code",
    COUNT(DISTINCT concat(latitude, longitude)) as locat_count,
    ST_Area(ST_Envelope(ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(ST_YMin(ST_Extent(ST_Transform(geog::geometry, 4326))), 
               ST_XMin(ST_Extent(ST_Transform(geog::geometry, 4326)))),
    ST_MakePoint(ST_YMax(ST_Extent(ST_Transform(geog::geometry, 4326))), 
               ST_XMax(ST_Extent(ST_Transform(geog::geometry, 4326))))
    )))*POWER(0.3048,2) as sqm
FROM
    geonames
WHERE
    "feature class" = 'P'
GROUP BY
    name,
    "country code"
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT concat(latitude, longitude)) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(DISTINCT concat(latitude, longitude)) DESC
```

As someone whose GIS experience is limited to reading [PostGIS in Action, 2nd edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291390), I'm hoping that the following questions can be answered:

1. Did I correctly transform a Geography to a Geometry data type, given that I'm doing an analysis of specific places across the entire globe?
2. Is using the area of a bounding box a good, but not great, measure of dispersion for this problem set?
3. Do you see anything I overlooked which will effect the quality of my analysis?